# What are the rules to build a database with large number of data?

Tags: database, database-design

I'm asking this question because I read a job advertise that states "design and manage database for handling large number of data" (MySQL).

I created and worked with many database, some very little (max 10 tables) and other bigger(30-40 tables).

My stupid question is: if I have to handle "large number of data" (many records or many tables) should I change the way I always created relational database??

Isnt' it, like with little database, an issue of relation between table,primary key, foreign key, constraints etc??

Sorry for this stupid question.

Comment: Well with very large tables things like indexing an optimization becomes more important, because a poorly tuned schema can be a performance killer.  Maybe they are expecting you to know this.

Comment: Read this bcs duplication of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611617/database-design-for-very-large-amount-of-data

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thank you, probably you are right, they expect me to know "index".

Comment: @Kasunt thank you, I'll read that post.